# Is there a way to know where jdoc:include type=head lines are being loaded from?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development

In a [previous question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/what-exactly-gets-loaded-inside-templates-jinclude-type-head-call) I already got clarified how exactly did `<jdoc:include type=head>` work. Now I have a new question about it.

Basically, any extension can add a call to new scripts, css files or tags that will be "catched" by the jdoc:include and injected in the `<head>` of the template.

**The question is**: is there a way to debug where each line loaded in the `<head`> by the include comes from?

For example, I had to work in a project where someone else provided a custom component with some custom modules, and I was seeing some strange stuff loaded in my `<head>`... so I had to inspect all view files one by one until I found which one was making the call that loaded those lines... is there a way to know where are these calls coming from? Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this will answer your query but the first thing I would do is look here:

> /libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php

In terms of modules adding 'strange' stuff; well they could for instance use `JFactory::getDocument()->addScript();` to add their own module JS, so I would check the module code for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i know that, and that's actually the kind of stuff I searched. I just wondered if there was any "flag" or something like that I could add to debugging so that I could know where exactly are those calls coming from in a debug view (maybe even in core's debug). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the best way to find out which component/module/plugin causes a particular head include is to use `grep` on the entire joomla installation.
Of course, this assumes that you know which resource URL to search for and that it shows up unobfuscated somewhere in the source code.

I needed to search for the plugin that caused font-awesome to be loaded from cloudflare's CDN, even though we already host and include a local version.
To determine the culprit, I used the following command:

```
grep -rnw /path/to/joomla/directory -e 'cdnjs\.cloudflare\.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome'
```